# WHERE 1 = 2 returns a row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

Any idea, why the first of the following queries returns a row with -1, NULL, although it has a `WHERE 1=2`?

Only when I put the query in another subquery it works correct (and returns an empty result set).

Tested on Microsoft SQL Server 2014 and 2016

```
DECLARE @i INT = 1

SELECT @i i, MAX(sub.id) mid
  FROM (SELECT TOP(@i) x.id
          FROM (VALUES(1), (2), (3), (4)) x(id)
         WHERE x.id > 2 + @i
         ORDER BY x.id) sub
WHERE 1 = 2

SELECT s1.i, s1.mid
  FROM (
        SELECT @i i, MAX(sub.id) mid
          FROM (SELECT TOP(@i) x.id
                  FROM (VALUES(1), (2), (3), (4)) x(id)
                 WHERE x.id > 2 + @i
                 ORDER BY x.id) sub
       ) s1
WHERE 1 = 2
```

Comment: @JonathanFite Make that an answer  :)

Comment: Check out [this post](http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2010/01/12/t-sql-tuesday-having-puzzle-answer/) by Rob Farley, as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An aggregate query without a `GROUP BY` is a *scalar aggregate* and (in the absence of any `HAVING` clause) returns exactly one row.

So if you do

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM EmptyTable
```

Or

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM SomeOtherTable
WHERE 1 = 0
```

Both would return the value `0` rather than an empty result set.

If you add a `GROUP BY` it then becomes a vector aggregate and returns one row per group (So would return nothing in the above examples) - See [Vector and scalar aggregates](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1570/html/sqlug/sqlug639.htm)

Your first query just consists of a scalar aggregate with `@i` added to the `SELECT` list so you get the single row. The second query has no aggregates of any kind and nothing matches the `WHERE` so you get no row.

**Further Reading**

[Fun with Aggregates - Paul White](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/03/12/fun-with-aggregates.aspx)